# Construction of S-box in AES

Tags: aes, s-boxes, rijndael

In my introductory cryptography class. There is a line describe the construction of S-box in AES
 "The S-box of AES is constructed by combining a function $h(x)=x^{254}$ defined on $GF(256)$  with an invertible affine transformation." 
However, when I look into the [Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) document](http://csrc.nist.gov/archive/aes/rijndael/Rijndael-ammended.pdf) , I can not find where the $h(x)=x^{254}$ is used. I understand that S-box is constructed by $a_{i,j}\to a_{i,j}^{-1}(mod\,x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1)$ and subsequent affine transformation. Does $h(x)=x^{254}=x^{-1}$ is used during the inverse proccess?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the field $GF(2^8)$, $x^{254} = x^{-1}$ (except for $x=0$, as $0^{-1}$ doesn't exist; for AES, that's treated as 0), and so it's two ways of describing the same thing.

When we talk about AES, we typically use the $x^{-1}$ nomenclature; for whatever reason, your class decided to go with the $x^{254}$ one.

Comment: Probably a silly question, but don't we require a modulus for the field multiplication?

Comment: @yyyy0000: one way to implement $GF(2^8)$ field multiplication using the representation that AES uses is, in fact, treat the values are polynomials on $GF(2)$, and to multiply two values, you would multiply the two polynomials, and then reduce the product modulo $x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1$.  However, when we're working the field (or ring or group), we typically just use the $\times$ or $+$ operations as the field operations, and don't explicitly write out how it could be implemented every time.